# Android adb severe error

Tags: android, adb

I've spent days trying to launch any Android program. Even "Hello World" gives me the same error: "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured".

i tried adb kill-server and after that adb start-server but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Kill the `adb.exe` process from Task Manager, and restart Eclipse. 
Shutting down your phone may help too.